# Change in Win32_Process

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting, administration

I wrote a bunch of functions using Win32_Process to query remote computers. Primarily I used it to get the owner of the processes running on the remote machine to find out which one was currently logged in, so I can do some user specific changes.

I upgraded to Powershell 7 and this has broke all of my functions I used win32_process in because, this class no longer has the getowner method or getownersid method.

I did notice in Powershell 7 console it is showing this

```
PS ~> get-wmiObject -Class win32_process | GM

TypeName: Deserialized.System.Management.ManagementObject#root\cimv2\Win32_Process
```

This is different when I am running in a Powershell 5 console

```
PS ~> get-wmiobject -Class win32_process | gm

TypeName: System.Management.ManagementObject#root\cimv2\Win32_Process
```

Is there a way I can change Powershell 7 to use the older style of Win32_process that Powershell 5 used?

I've looked online, but haven't seen anything on these changes of win32_process. The place I work at does not have WinRM turned on, so changing to CIMInstance isn't an option for me at this moment.

Comment: WMI Cmdlets are deprecated, you can still use `GetOwner` with CIM Cmdlets: `Get-CimInstance Win32_Process | Invoke-CimMethod -MethodName GetOwner`. Also "the place I work at does not have WinRM turned on, so changing to CIMInstance isn't an option for me at this moment.". That's not a problem, CIM Cmdlets can use DCOM as the transport protocol: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/cimcmdlets/new-cimsessionoption?view=powershell-7.3#-protocol

Comment: Can you tell us what specific problem you're hoping to solve?

Comment: Thank you Santiago, that was an easy fix!